# Capture the ambient sound

Tags: filter-design, speech-processing, noise-cancellation, lms, speech-synthesis

I sit in a cafe and start recording my voice, reading a poem. Then I sit at my room, at complete isolation, and I read the same exact poem once again and record it.

Now, Considering I have these two recordings, How can I capture the ambient sounds in the cafe? in fact, how can I cancel my own sound from the cafe-recorded-sound?

I already did LMS to enhance my voice in the cafe-recorded-sound. Then when I subtract the resulted enhanced speech from the original mixed track, I still cannot have the ambient sound.

What should I do?

Comment: I guess not reading the poem in the first place and just recording the ambience is not an option? In any case, there's next to no correlation between two independent recordings of the same spoken text, so your second recording is not really of much help. What is the actual real-world problem that you want to solve?

Comment: :)), you are right buddy, my main question is, "how to seperate ambient sound from your speech?" Other than ICA, can you help me with any solution ?